# How to strict an area in file with awk?

Tags: awk

I have a long text file and I need to provide computation with a table that is in this large text file, so I am trying to restrict the area and print only the table I need. The area I care about looks like:

```
Sums of squares of residuals for separate curves, including only individual weights


Curve     No. of obs.   Sum of squares
  1           82        0.20971070
  2         7200    13659.50038631
  3         7443    15389.87972458
  4         5843    10510.37305696
  5          290    49918.40634886
  6         1376    49974.57509390
  7          694     8340.44771461
  8          545     2476.43037281
  9          349     1425.69687357



 1111 1111 0101110 01110 11001 01111 11110 0 1 1 0.100D-02


   UNWEIGHTED OBSERVATIONAL EQUATIONS
No.  Curve    Input Param.        Correction     Output Param.    Standard Deviation
 9      0     39.6398000000      0.0796573846     39.7194573846      0.6864389887
```

I tried this, but all file is printed

```
/Curve/ { in_f_format=0; next }
/UNWEIGHTED/ { in_f_format=1; next }
{print}
```

desired output

```
  1           82        0.20971070
  2         7200    13659.50038631
  3         7443    15389.87972458
  4         5843    10510.37305696
  5          290    49918.40634886
  6         1376    49974.57509390
  7          694     8340.44771461
  8          545     2476.43037281
  9          349     1425.69687357
```

Comment: `awk 'NF==3 && $1~/^[0-9]/' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: according to your desired output, you can use this:

```
awk '/Curve/ { in_f_format=1; next } /^[[:space:]]*$/ { in_f_format=0; next } in_f_format'
```

If you only want the content between the two patterns, change your code to this would work:

```
/Curve/ { in_f_format=1; next }
/UNWEIGHTED/ { in_f_format=0; next }
in_f_format {print}
```

The things before the blocks are considered conditions, when a condition evaluates to `true`, then the block after it will be executed.
A block without a condition will be executed by default (when not skipped by `next` or other thing).
Additionally, a condition without a block will have `{print}` implied, so it can be saved here.

For example, `file` with the content you provided:

```
$ awk '/Curve/ { in_f_format=1; next } /UNWEIGHTED/ { in_f_format=0; next } in_f_format' file
  1           82        0.20971070
  2         7200    13659.50038631
  3         7443    15389.87972458
  4         5843    10510.37305696
  5          290    49918.40634886
  6         1376    49974.57509390
  7          694     8340.44771461
  8          545     2476.43037281
  9          349     1425.69687357



 1111 1111 0101110 01110 11001 01111 11110 0 1 1 0.100D-02
```

Another example, starting from *Curve* title line to before empty line:

```
$ awk '/Curve/ { in_f_format=1; } /^[[:space:]]*$/ { in_f_format=0; next } in_f_format' file
Curve     No. of obs.   Sum of squares                                                      
  1           82        0.20971070                                                          
  2         7200    13659.50038631                                                          
  3         7443    15389.87972458                                                          
  4         5843    10510.37305696                                                          
  5          290    49918.40634886                                                          
  6         1376    49974.57509390                                                          
  7          694     8340.44771461                                                          
  8          545     2476.43037281                                                          
  9          349     1425.69687357
```

Unassigned variables have `0` or empty value by default, which evaluates to `false`.
The `[[:space:]]*` is for lines have space characters, if you want strictly speaking empty line, then just `/^$/` where `^` means line-beginning and `$` means line-ending.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice that in a original large file is string 'Curve' after this table too. Is it possible restrict area that is start with `/Curve/ { in_f_format=1; next }` and end with empty row that follow in this case after row with 9?

Comment: @LukášAltman Remove the `next` in this block, and change the regex in the condition of the other block will do. i.e. change `/UNWEIGHTED/` to `/^[[:space:]]*$/`.